# Thales HSM PIN Related Operations

Tags: encryption, hsm

We are developing mobile banking apps in which case we want to have PIN related with Thales Payshield 9000 HSM.

We have device and manual with us, but official documentation is such poor can't head start anything. I need to do following operations.

HSM is ready with test LMK loaded, and generated ZMK, TPK keys.

- PIN Generate
- PIN Change
- PIN Verify

till now I have used following commands via Java sockets:

1. JA - Generate a Random PIN
2. NC - Perform Diagnostics
3. NO - HSM Status

Can anyone help me how we should move forward?

Answer (score 1):

full disclosure.. i work for Thales :-)

The functions are covered by the following commands:

**PIN Generate** - JA
e.g.: `JA12345678901204` should return something like `JB0027743` where `27743` is a PIN encrypted under the LMK. This can then be fed into a subsequent command to generate an offset or PVK. For a PVK the DG command could be used as follows (space delimited to show how the command is structured):

```
DG UE741620A9C289D6241882E8028BCD4B4 29840 1234567890120
```

returns

```
DH 00 7935
```

**PIN Change** - DU/CU

**PIN Verify** - could be a number of commands depending on the method being used

It looks like you're able to send NC to the device. are you getting a proper response, ie, ND followed by the firmware version and KCV? eg:

```
ND 00 2686040000000000 1346-0910
```

Are you having a issue forming the command?

without knowing more about the problem it's difficult to provide a fuller answer.

Can i suggest that you email our support team and reference the discussion. They can then forward your email to me internally..

Comment: can you please share the support email to my email address, faisalx64@gmail.com Thanks

Comment: Thanks but actually we have to send user's generated PIN via SMS because we are opening their mobile wallet accounts. 

So, after having encrypted PIN via JA/JB what should I do to send clear text PIN to user via SMS.